# Show that $\chi=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int _M d^2 \sigma g^{1/2} R +\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial M}ds k$ is locally a total derivative in 2D

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory

In Polchinski Page 83 mentioned that

> $$\chi=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int _M d^2 \sigma g^{1/2} R +\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial M}ds k$$ is locally a total derivative in two dimension

> $R$ was the Ricci scalar constructed from $g_{ab}$(Page 15), $ds$ the proper time along the boundary in the metric $g_{ab}$, and the geodesic curvature $k$ was defined on Page 30 as
> $$k=\pm t^a n_b\nabla_at^b$$
> where $t^a$ was a unit vector tangent to the boundary and $n^a$ an outward pointing unit vector orthogonal to $t^a$

How to show that $\chi$ was locally a total derivative in 2D?